# How to get JSON data from HTML using jsoup

Tags: java, android, json, android-webview, jsoup

I am hitting a URL in WebView which returns a response in HTML format. I have tried to get JSON data from that HTML using Jsoup but not able to get that.

I am getting data in below format :

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"status":"success","connected_id":"dfdffdffdfdfdf"}</pre>
```

Now I want to get that `connected_id` from the above response but I am not able to get that.

Code :

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = document.select("pre");
Log.d("TAG", " myHTMLResponseCallback1 : " + elements.attr("pre"));
```

I am not getting any value in `elements.attr("connected_id")`.

Comment: What is the value of `elements`?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to retrive json data from html with jsoup is extract json through data() method:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element element = document.selectFirst("pre#id");
String jsonText = element .data();
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is that your `<pre>` element contains a JSON string, which can not be parsed using Jsoup. The first step anyway is to extract the JSON string:

```
String html = "<pre style=\"word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;\">{\"status\":\"success\",\"connected_id\":\"dfdffdffdfdfdf\"}</pre>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element element = document.selectFirst("pre");
String json = element.text();
```

The simplest, but probably not the best way to extract the `connected_id` from the JSON string would be using a regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"connected_id\":\"(?<id>.*)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String connectedId = matcher.group("id");
    // ...
}
```

A better way would be to parse the JSON string. You can achieve this using a JSON parsing library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [others](https://json.org/).

Here is an example using Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
String connectedId = jsonNode.get("connected_id").asText();
```

If you want to extract some more values (not only the `connected_id`) I would suggest transforming the JSON string to a Java object like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("connected_id")
    private String connectedId;
    // more attributes if you need them

    // getter and setter
}
```

You now can use this class to read the json value:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObject result = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
String connectedId = result.getConnectedId();
```

All solutions will return `dfdffdffdfdfdf` as result.