# JSoup Document object, how to parse data in below case of complex html element?

Tags: json, jsoup

URL : https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/auto-23-wheelers/bajajauto/BA10

I'm getting below document doc.select("#C-12-graph").get(0)

```
<div id="C-12-graph" style="display: none;">[{"heading":"Revenue","data":[{"year":"2018","value":"25218","formattedValue":"25,218 Cr"},{"year":"2019","value":"30357","formattedValue":"30,357 Cr"},{"year":"2020","value":"29918","formattedValue":"29,918 Cr"},{"year":"2021","value":"27741","formattedValue":"27,741 Cr"},{"year":"2022","value":"33144","formattedValue":"33,144 Cr"}]},{"heading":"Net Profit","data":[{"year":"2018","value":"3931","formattedValue":"3,931 Cr"},{"year":"2019","value":"4577","formattedValue":"4,577 Cr"},{"year":"2020","value":"4890","formattedValue":"4,890 Cr"},{"year":"2021","value":"4550","formattedValue":"4,550 Cr"},{"year":"2022","value":"5586","formattedValue":"5,586 Cr"}]},{"heading":"EPS","data":[{"year":"2018","value":"145.80","formattedValue":"145.80"},{"year":"2019","value":"170.30","formattedValue":"170.30"},{"year":"2020","value":"180.20","formattedValue":"180.20"},{"year":"2021","value":"167.90","formattedValue":"167.90"},{"year":"2022","value":"213.20","formattedValue":"213.20"}]},{"heading":"BVPS","data":[{"year":"2018","value":"705.85","formattedValue":"705.85"},{"year":"2019","value":"802.91","formattedValue":"802.91"},{"year":"2020","value":"748.59","formattedValue":"748.59"},{"year":"2021","value":"942.51","formattedValue":"942.51"},{"year":"2022","value":"1031.89","formattedValue":"1,031.89"}]},{"heading":"ROE","data":[{"year":"2018","value":"20.65","formattedValue":"20.65"},{"year":"2019","value":"21.20","formattedValue":"21.20"},{"year":"2020","value":"24.06","formattedValue":"24.06"},{"year":"2021","value":"17.80","formattedValue":"17.80"},{"year":"2022","value":"20.64","formattedValue":"20.64"}]},{"heading":"Debt to Equity","data":[{"year":"2018","value":"0.00","formattedValue":"0.00"},{"year":"2019","value":"0.00","formattedValue":"0.00"},{"year":"2020","value":"0.00","formattedValue":"0.00"},{"year":"2021","value":"0.00","formattedValue":"0.00"},{"year":"2022","value":"0.00","formattedValue":"0.00"}]}]</div>
```

From this I would like to get data for below heading values Revenue, Net Profit etc and below them yearly data values

e.g. heading = Revenue,  2018 = 25218, 2019 = 30357

Please clarify how to do this with Jsoup Document object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for cannot be done using jsoup, you have to use a json parser.
If you run the following code (with the right url) -

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();        
Element data = doc.select("#C-12-graph").get(0);
String jsonArray = data.text();
```

then the content of `jsonArray` is actually a json array, and `jsoup` treats it as plain text.
You can use the following example, which is using the java-json library (can be found [here](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java), but there are plenty of other parsers) -

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonobject.getString("heading");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

and the output is -

> Revenue
> Net Profit
> EPS
> BVPS
> ROE
> Debt to Equity

The same way you can parse all the details that you need.

Comment: Thanks, I could figure it out as well. Please check below answer. I've accepted your as solution.

Answer (score 0):

References:

[Extracting data from JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058240/extracting-data-from-json-array)

[How to get JSON data from HTML using jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073103/how-to-get-json-data-from-html-using-jsoup)

[A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] with '{' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062056/a-jsonobject-text-must-begin-with-at-1-character-2-line-1-with-error)

[How to Remove Square bracket from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699452/how-to-remove-square-bracket-from-json)

https://www.jsonformatter.io/

```
            String cssQueryToConsolidatedFinancials = "#C-12-graph";
            String year, revenue;

            System.out.println("Net Profit Last 5 years");

            JSONObject revenueJSONObj = new JSONArray( doc.selectFirst(cssQueryToConsolidatedFinancials).text() ).getJSONObject(1);

            if(revenueJSONObj.getString("heading").equals("Net Profit") ){
                for( int cnt = 0; cnt < revenueJSONObj.getJSONArray("data").length(); cnt++){
                    year = revenueJSONObj.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(cnt).getString("year");
                    revenue = revenueJSONObj.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(cnt).getString("value");
                    System.out.println(year + "  " + revenue);
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }

            System.out.println("STOP");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```